# php - generate a 4 digit number

Tags: php, random, numbers

For the captcha, the code below generates a 5-digit number. I want it to be 4 digits. how can I do it.

```
// generate random numbers
$sayilar = '';
for ($x = 15; $x <= 95; $x += 20) {
    $sayilar .= ($sayi = rand(0, 9));
    imagechar($image, rand(3, 5), $x, rand(2, 14), $sayi, $textcolor);
}
```

Comment: Change `<= 95` to `<= 75`. Then you'll get X positions 15, 35, 55, 75, which is 4 digits.

Comment: Or change `<=` to `<` so it doesn't include `$x = 95`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop definition is convoluted since you've loaded a lot of unnecessary logic into it. It would be more clear and easier to modify/maintain as:

```
$sayilar = '';
$lpad = 15;
$offset = 20;
for ($x = 0; $x < 4; ++$x) {
    $sayilar .= ($sayi = rand(0, 9));
    $xpos = $x * $offset + $lpad;
    imagechar($image, rand(3, 5), $xpos, rand(2, 14), $sayi, $textcolor);
}
```